# Conflict between two jQuery

Tags: html

I paste the script for a video and I getting conflict when I paste the video script it make to stop my menu and slider using another version of jQuery, how I can fix it?

This is my head:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Beautiful_ES_italic_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/OptimusPrincepsSemiBold_600.font.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Start VideoLightBox.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_videolb/videolightbox.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_videolb/overlay-minimal.css"/>
    <script src="index_videolb/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="index_videolb/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End VideoLightBox.com HEAD section -->
```

This is the Body section:

```
<!-- Start VideoLightBox.com BODY section -->
    <div class="videogallery">
        <a class="voverlay" href="index_videolb/vdbplayer.swf?volume=100&url=video/devocional.mov" title="Devocional">
            <img src="index_videolb/thumbnails/devocional.png" alt="Devocional" /><span></span>
        </a>
        <span class="videolb">
            <a class="videolb" href="http://videolightbox.com">Lightbox in Flash</a> by VideoLightBox.com v2.7m
        </span>
    </div>
    <script src="index_videolb/jquery.tools.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="index_videolb/videolightbox.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End VideoLightBox.com BODY section -->
```

Comment: Only include one version of jQuery

Comment: I agree. Find out what version of jQuery the VideoLightBox file is, and only use that one. Unless it's super old and affects functionality on the rest of your page - in which case, take a look at `jQuery.noConflict()`: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the VideoLightBox site, it looks like it uses jQuery 1.9.1. If that version is compatible with the rest of your code, you can move `index_videolb/jquery.js` to the top and remove 1.7.1...

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
<script src="index_videolb/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-yui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/cufon-replace.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/Beautiful_ES_italic_400.font.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/OptimusPrincepsSemiBold_600.font.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="Scripts/swfobject_modified.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Start VideoLightBox.com HEAD section -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index_videolb/videolightbox.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index_videolb/overlay-minimal.css"/>
    <script src="index_videolb/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- End VideoLightBox.com HEAD section -->
```

Comment: Also I tried to include the script jQuery.noConflict(): but it didn't works either!